# Esconder uma imagem ao passar o mouse em cima da div

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer com que uma imagem desapareça ao passar o mouse em cima da `div` mas estou com um problema: quando passo o mouse a imagem desaparece, mas não consigo clicar no link da div de trás.
Código:

```
<div class="col-md-8"> 
<div class="elemento-um"> 
<!-- LightWidget WIDGET -->
</div></div>

<div class="ico">
<a href='#'><img src='icon.png' /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.elemento-um {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     margin-top: -127px;
     height: 107px;
     overflow: hidden; 
} 

.ico {
     opacity: 1;
     top: -140px;
     transition: .5s ease;
     z-index: 111;
     position: absolute; 
}

.ico a{ 
display: none; 
visibility:visible; 
} 

.ico:hover a {  
visibility: block; 
}
```

Comment: Lia só pelo seu relato é impossível te dar uma resposta precisa. Por favor, edite sua pergunta colocando o código HTML e CSS que vc tem. E se possível faça o Tour do site para entender melhor como funciona aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Adicionalmente ao comentário do @hugocsl, a página [ask] vai direto ao ponto. É sempre recomendável incluir um [mcve].

Comment: @hugocsl, desculpe, não sabia. Editei a pergunta com o código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lia,

Pelo código parece estar ao contrário do que você perguntou, então vou responder baseado na sua pergunta.

A propriedade `visibility:block` não existe, o correto seria `visility:visible`. O block é do display. `display:block`.

O `display:none` esconde o elemento da tela, já o `visibility:hidden` deixa o elemento lá só que esconde o conteúdo.

Mas para esse caso não serviria colocar `display:none` no hover porque quando der hover no elemento vai esconder ele e como escondeu não vai mais estar em hover então o elemento irá aparecer de novo e ficar "piscando" na tela aparecendo e desaparecendo.

o ideal seria colocar um `opacity:0` na imagem quando der hover na div.ico.

Ex:

```
.elemento-um {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     margin-top: -127px;
     height: 107px;
     overflow: hidden; 
} 

.ico {
     opacity: 1;
     top: -140px;
     transition: .5s ease;
     z-index: 111;
     position: absolute; 
}

.ico:hover a {  
   visibility:hidden
}
```

Segue um fiddle de exemplo:

> https://jsfiddle.net/ey0m7rta/9/

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigada por tirar um tempo para me ajudar! Era exatamente isso. Desculpe também pelo erro, me confundi na hora de publicar. Tenha uma ótima noite!